# Room database, setting nullable @Embedded data class to null with an insert query (OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) causes NPE on non-null inner fields

Tags: android, android-room

Is there a way to set nullable `@Embedded` data classes in Room to `null` while inserting with `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`? I am doing this at the moment:

```
//in dao
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertImage(image: ImageEntity)
```

and the entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "images")
data class ImageEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val imageGuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @Embedded(prefix = "server_")
    val serverImage: ServerImageEntity? = null,
    @Embedded(prefix ="device_")
    val deviceImage: DeviceImageEntity? = null
)

data class ServerImageEntity(
    val imageGuid: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String?,
    val url: String,
    val status: SyncStatus = SyncStatus.IDLE
)

data class DeviceImageEntity(
    val imageGuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val name: String = "",
    val description: String? = null,
    val uri: Uri,
    val status: SyncStatus = SyncStatus.IDLE
)
```

when I try to call it like so:

```
val image = database.imageDao.getImageByGuid(imageGuid)
//later on
database.imageDao.insertImage(image.copy(serverImage = null))
```

I get a NPE saying that `imageGuid` for `serverImage` is null. Is it possible to set nullable `@Embedded` fields back to null once they are initially set?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set nullable @Embedded fields back to null once they are initially set?

I believe that the following rule has to be met for it to be possible :-

> When an embedded field is read, if **all** fields of the embedded
>   field (and its sub fields) are null in the Cursor, it is set to null.
>   **Otherwise, it is constructed.**
>
> [Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded.html)

Comment: That is what I thought :-( Unfortunately don't want to make all the inner fields nullable as if the entity is not null they have to be non-null. I am just deleting it and re-adding it without the `serverImage` for now. Hopefully they will add this functionality at some point :-)